# html5 3d, canvas, three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js

I have the following HTML

```
<canvas id="container" name ="container" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

and JavaScript code

```
var WIDTH = 400, HEIGHT = 300;
var VIEW_ANGLE = 90, ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR = 1, FAR = 300;

renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE,ASPECT,NEAR,FAR);
camera.position.z = 200;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);

renderer.render( scene, camera );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
//$('#container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

$('#container').width(WIDTH);
$('#container').height(HEIGHT);

function getSphere() {
    var radius = 50, segments = 16, rings = 16;
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius,segments,rings);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xCC0000
    });
    return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
}
```

`document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );` works,

But how to write into canvas with jQuery?

`$('#container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);` does not work.

Comment: I've noticed that the quality of answers is slowly diminishing as the reputation system becomes more popular.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this:

```
$('#container').append(renderer.domElement);
```

`$('#container')` returns a jQuery Object, where `appendChild()` is a JavaScript method which works with a JavaScript DOM element, but not with a jQuery object.

Therefore, to append use the jQuery method ***[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append)***.

---

As your `#container` is a `canvas` element, it does not support the `appendChild()` method. Instead  you can change it to a `div` like:

```
<div id="container" name="container" style:"width:300;height:300"></div>
```

and then try with:

```
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

***OR***

```
$('#container').append(renderer.domElement);
```

Here, you do not need to add a `<canvas>` either, because `renderer.domElement` is a `canvas` element. For example, in ***[this link](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_bumpmap.html)***, the view source shows there is no `<canvas>` in the `HTML`. Instead, it creates a `div` by JavaScript, appends that to the `DOM` and at last appends the `renderer.domElement` (which is `<canvas>`) to that `div`.

Comment: this $('#container')[0].appendChild(renderer.domElement); also does not work. can anybody give a working hint?